# pytorch, AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute '_utils_internal'

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, anaconda, fast-ai

I need to test some fastai models in an environment without GPU, specifically in a windows server. I trained some fastai models in Google colab, and now need to test them in real time, connected to an industrial process. Nevertheless I'm limited with hardware.

In Google colab, I worked with this configuration.

```
from fastai.vision import *
from fastai.metrics import error_rate
from PIL import Image as PImage
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import pandas as pd
```

The first line is the onlyone that has the trouble is the first one, and I get this error:

```
  ~\.conda\envs\fastai_1\lib\site-packages\fastai\vision\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .learner import *

  ~\.conda\envs\fastai_1\lib\site-packages\fastai\vision\learner.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import models

  ~\.conda\envs\fastai_1\lib\site-packages\fastai\vision\models\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from torchvision.models import ResNet,resnet18,resnet34,resnet50,resnet101,resnet152

  ~\.conda\envs\fastai_1\lib\site-packages\torchvision\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .extension import _HAS_OPS

  ~\.conda\envs\fastai_1\lib\site-packages\torchvision\extension.py", line 51, in <module>
    _register_extensions()

  ~\.conda\envs\fastai_1\lib\site-packages\torchvision\extension.py", line 47, in _register_extensions
    torch.ops.load_library(ext_specs.origin)

  ~\.conda\envs\fastai_1\lib\site-packages\torch\_ops.py", line 99, in load_library
    path = torch._utils_internal.resolve_library_path(path)

AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute '_utils_internal'
```

I had to installed Pytorch with conda as was suggested by pytorch start locally https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/, but for fastai I had to installed using pip. Conda doesn't work in my limited hardware in the server

```
# for Pytorch
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch
# for fastai
python -m pip install fastai==1.0.61
```

My torch version is 1.9.0
My python version is 3.7.7

I checked several similar threads, with different attribute that is not found, but, all are related to that specific error, not '_utils_internal'

I appreciate any help

Comment: Did you find any answer yet? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: I encountered this exact error when trying to use `torchmetrics`. Downgrading from 0.9.3 to 0.7.0 worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem (Pytorch 1.11.0, Torchvision 0.12.0, CUDA 11.3, Python 3.10) and came around with a somewhat "hacky" solution.

First I checked the file _ops.py in the given location, it contained indeed the statements and function:

```
import torch._utils_internal
...
path = torch._utils_internal.resolve_library_path(path)
```

Also _utils_internal.py was available and contained the statements and function:

```
import os
...
def resolve_library_path(path: str) -> str:
    return os.path.realpath(path)
```

As I didn't really understand, what the issue was, I just decided to copy the returned expression into the _ops.py file and add the os import. So this now contains:

```
import os
...
path = os.path.realpath(path)
```

And it works!