# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute '_utils_internal'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, d2l

```
import numpy as np

from d2l import torch as d2l
import torch
from torch.utils import data
```

My torch version is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2UVK.png)
When I run the code above, I face the problem as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6tcb.png)

This is the jupyter files of "https://d2l.ai/".I just used the torch version following the official doc, but I could not reach the same and encountered this problem.
I would appreciate the answer

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68274836/pytorch-attributeerror-module-torch-has-no-attribute-utils-internal) answer your question?

Comment: Did you try to upgrade torch library or unistall and reinstall?

Comment: Have your local system installed the [d2l.ai](https://d2l.ai/chapter_installation/index.html) library? It's not there in the setup details image you shared.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)